# How do I shift a number x decimal places to the left or right and remove minus sign?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets Script, how can I take a value from a cell and then shift it e.g. 2 decimal places to the left or right and also remove the minus sign.

For example if I take a value from a cell that is -0.25 how can I transform it to 25 and then use this value in the script.

Thanks

Comment: The question as asked doesn't really make sense. Under what circumstances would you move the the decimal pont to the left?

Answer (score 2):

You could take the absolute value of the multiplication of the value with 100.

```js
var value = -0.25,
    result = Math.abs(value * 100);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x=-.25;
console.log(Math.sqrt(x*x)*100);
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with a textual explanation of the code snippet and explain how it answers the question

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like:

```
function myFunction() {

  var value = -0.2512

  // Get the numbers after the '.', and count them
  var decimals = value.toString().split('.')[1].split('').length;

  // Multiply 10 for the amount of numbers after the '.'
  var multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimals)

  var result = Math.abs(value * multiplier);

  Logger.log(result);
}
```

So you can have either `0.2` or `0.222222` because it counts how many numbers go after the coma and then uses it to know if you have to multiply by 10, 100, 1000, etc.